# AES key moved in config file generate " AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long" error

Tags: python, encryption, configuration, flask, aes

I'm using python,flask.I'm doing encryption with AES. It works good, I encrypt and decrypt data easly . 
To secure the encryption key i moved my encryption key from app form in config file. First I saved a variable in a config file,I declared `ENCRYPTION_KEY` in  `config.cfg` .

```
[Encryption]
ENCRYPTION_KEY = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
```

and then on init file i declared:

```
 app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY'] = config.get('Encryption', 'ENCRYPTION_KEY')
```

I tried accessing it from `key = flask.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY']`. I print key in console just to be sure that the command works:

```
def encrypt_data(self, form_data):
        key = current_app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY']
        print "KEY : " , key
        cipher = AES.new(key)
        //code...
```

And in console key is printed:
[image: console]

Now when i try to use this key from config file,i have an error message:
[image: AES error]

This message appears only because i moved that key in config file, because as I said before i used the same key for the same methods and it works perfectly? 
Can anybody help me, why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? The `print` statement looks like Python 2, however, it's output looks like Python 3.

Comment: @mhawke I'm using Python 2.7.6

Comment: @EgzontinaK:  That's not possible. Python 2 will not print out the key as a byte string with a leading `b`. How are you loading your config file? Is there any chance that you have actually set `ENCRYPTION_KEY = "b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'"` , i.e. the string actually includes the `b` prefix?

Comment: @mhawke I updated my question, as i wrote  i just add it on init file and i can access that with the b prefix before the string , i only used  single quotation marks ('') in config file!

Comment: @EgzontinaK: ConfigParser returns raw strings, i.e, backslashes are escaped with additional backslashes and this results in a string of 92 characters including the `b` prefix and surrounding quotes. See my answer for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the `ConfigParser` module is the cause of the problem. Given the config file shown:

```
>>> config.get('Encryption', 'ENCRYPTION_KEY')
"b'\\xbf\\xc0\\x85)\\x10nc\\x94\\x02)j\\xdf\\xcb\\xc4\\x94\\x9d(\\x9e[EX\\xc8\\xd5\\xbfI{\\xa2$\\x05(\\xd5\\x18'"
>>> len(config.get('Encryption', 'ENCRYPTION_KEY'))
92
```

you can see here that `ConfigParser` simply returns the value associated with the given config variable as *text*, not as a Python string. Because the config value contains backslash escape sequences, these backslashes are escaped with additional backslashes. This breaks the `\x` character sequences which then blow out to 4 characters.

The easiest way around this is to use Flask's config files:

*config.cfg*

```
ENCRYPTION_KEY = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
```

```
>>> import flask
>>> app = flask.Flask('test')
>>> app = flask.Flask('')
>>> app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')
True
>>> app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY']
'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
>>> len(app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY'])
32
```

If you do not want to use Flask's config files your options are (in order of preference):

- Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely convert the raw string into a Python string:

  ```
  from ast import literal_eval
  app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY'] = literal_eval(config.get('Encryption', 'ENCRYPTION_KEY'))
  ```
- Base64 encode the value in the config file, e.g.

  ```
  [Encryption]
  ENCRYPTION_KEY = v8CFKRBuY5QCKWrfy8SUnSieW0VYyNW/SXuiJAUo1Rg=
  ```

  Then decode it when you access the key:

  ```
  app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY'] = config.get('Encryption', 'ENCRYPTION_KEY').decode('base64')
  ```
- Use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to convert the raw string into a Python string:

  ```
  app.config['ENCRYPTION_KEY'] = eval(config.get('Encryption', 'ENCRYPTION_KEY'))
  ```

  although this is considered bad/dangerous practice and you would be better off using `literal_eval()` or base64 encoding.
- Store the key as a binary value in the file:

  ```
  [Encryption]
  ENCRYPTION_KEY = ¿À<85>)^Pnc<94>^B)jßËÄ<94><9d>(<9e>[EXÈÕ¿I{¢$^E(Õ^X
  ```

  but that is very difficult to maintain.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot :)